# OpenCV: Error trying to stitch images

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to create kind of a panorama using the `Stitcher::stitch` function on OpenCV.

I take around 24 pictures to stitch them but the final result (Status = OK) is a 1x1 image (black pixel).

If I remove some of the images, it works OK but maybe I'm missing some parts of the image.

What am I doing bad?
Thank you in advance.

Update:

I'm trying to add rois taking the 50% of every image.
For the first image I take the right 50%. For the last, the left 50%, and for the rest I take 50% of left and 50% of right:

```
vector<Mat> imgs;
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0073.jpg"));
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0074.jpg"));
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0075.jpg"));
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0076.jpg"));
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0077.jpg"));
imgs.push_back(imread("/Users/myImages/IMG_0078.jpg"));

processImage(imgs);
```

and my function is:

void processImage(vector imgs){

```
vector<vector<Rect>> rois;
vector<Rect> roisVect;
for (int j = 0; j < imgs.size(); j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
        Rect rect1 = Rect(imgs.at(j).cols*50/100, 0, imgs.at(j).cols*50/100,imgs.at(j).rows);
        roisVect.push_back(rect1);
        rois.push_back(roisVect);
        
        roisVect.clear();
    } else if (j == imgs.size() - 1) {
        Rect rect2 = Rect(0, 0, imgs.at(j).cols*50/100, imgs.at(j).rows);
        roisVect.push_back(rect2);
        rois.push_back(roisVect);
        
        roisVect.clear();
    } else {
        Rect rect3 = Rect(imgs.at(j).cols*50/100, 0, imgs.at(j).cols*50/100, imgs.at(j).rows);
        Rect rect4 = Rect(0, 0, imgs.at(j).cols*50/100, imgs.at(j).rows);
        roisVect.push_back(rect4);
        roisVect.push_back(rect3);
        rois.push_back(roisVect);
        
        roisVect.clear();
    }
    
}
Mat pano;
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, rois, pano);
cout << endl << status;
cout << endl << pano.size();
if (!pano.empty())
    imshow("pano", pano);
waitKey(10);

imwrite("/Users/myImages/final" + to_string(imgs.size()) + ".jpg", pano);
```

}

And my results (cout) are:

> 0 // (OK)
>
> [1 x 1]

Comment: My crystal ball is in repair atm... maybe try `Stitcher::estimateTransform` followed by a `Stitcher::composePanorama` and have a look at the intermediate transformation results?!?

Comment: @Micka thank you for your reply. You are completely right with your crystal ball, it wasn't that explained, but I don't know how to expand the details if I get an `OK` result... haha. I'm going to do this and I will reply you back in a while.

Comment: @Micka could you specify me how to see the intermediate transformations results?? because `Stitcher::estimateTransform` returns a Status (and in my case it's `OK`)

Comment: you are right, `Sticher` manages all the transformations internally... `Stitcher` is a very hight lvl "method", that doesnt give much insight about WHY something does work or not. I've implemented my own stitching pipeline long time ago, and from my experience it isnt easy to decide automatically, whether stitching was successful or not. but maybe someone else has an idea. good luck